# Playing music through entire app (game) - when to release MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, android-activity, release, android-mediaplayer

I am making a simple game and I want to loop few songs when app is in foreground using MediaPlayer. Playback should stop when UI is not visible, so I decided to play it from activities and not a service.

The problem is that the app consists of multiple activities so I cant just pause it in every onPause, but I have figured that out.

*What I cant figure out so far, is to when and where should I release MediaPlayer and other (SoundPool) resources, as there is no onDestroy with Applications as far as I know. **Is there any way to figure out how many activities do I have left on the stack and when the last calls Activity.onDestroy(), release it there?***

Thanks!

Comment: Based on what I've read about this a few months ago. It is not advisable to use MediaPlayer to do a playblack of music in background instead use SoundPool. see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html

Comment: Why is that? AFAIK SoundPool is for sound bites, MediaPlayer is for songs. Btw that doesnt really answer my question, SoundPool needs releasing too.

Comment: @VlastoBennyLava you are correct, SoundPool is not intended for long running clips. MediaPlayer is the better choice for songs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a Service. Put your MediaPlayer and other resources in the Service. Bind each Activity to the Service in onStart as described in [the Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) and unbind in onStop. The Service will shut down when all components are unbound.

Comment: Awesome, that exactly what I want.